# How to detect if user disconnected or closed the app in Swift Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to detect if user is disconnected, or closed the app on Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Firebase Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore doesn't have a presence system. From the [Build Presence in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) documentation:

> Cloud Firestore doesn't natively support presence, but you can leverage other Firebase products to build a presence system.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in presence management in Firestore like there is in Realtime Database.

[Read this for possible alternatives.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence)